# R bubble plot x axis scale

Tags: r, symbols

I have a data frame like so;

```
yr.class   t2  Height_increment

1983    1   12.139344
1984    1   11.621212
1985    1   17.324176
1986    1   16.515504
1987    1   16.359195
1988    1   15.223077
1989    1   15.522972
1990    1   19.207658
1991    1   20.142740
1992    1   19.143021
1993    1   17.280922
1994    1   17.381966
1995    1   16.893162
```

I have produced the following bubble plot which is fine;

```
radius <- sqrt( df$Height_increment/ pi )
symbols(df$yr.class, df$t2, circles=radius, inches=0.25, fg="black", bg="red", xlab="Year class", ylab="Age")
```

However i want to know if there is a way of stretching the x axis so that the bubbles only overlap verticly. I know that it must be possible as I have seen many with such a layout in publications. I have tried altering the size of the 'inches' but this just makes them too small to visibly see differences.

Thanks
Helen

[image: An example of the type of layout desired]

Comment: Please change the variable names so they are the same in the example data and in the code. Please also insert a picture of the desired plot, it will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry Henrik, hopefully the revised version is clearer.

Comment: The easiest is to just make your graphing window wider and replot. Or, you use device parameters and set the width and height of what you want to plot. You just need to select an output device, pdf, quartz, png, etc.